# Want to read key value from properties File

Tags: javascript, file

I have a properties file , now using javascript code i want to read key value from the properties file.

Comment: Please be more specific on your task and environment. Are you talking about reading local file that is on your filesystem, from a web-browser?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about javascript reading local file from a web-browser, then you can't do that due to security limitations. On the other hand, Javascript can read a remote file from a web-site using different techniques (AJAX, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this jquery plugin :
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery. Your properties file may be in JSON format. Then you can use this :

```
jQuery.getJSON( your_properties_file_url );
```